# call a method with NSDate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im writing a simple clock app and am looking for a way to call a method when the hour changes (or minute of second etc etc). If someone could point me in the right direction for this i would much appreciate it.Perhaps the kind of instance that calls a method for an alarm, im not sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could schedule an NSTimer with [`-initWithFireDate:...`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-BBCGEHGC), with the fire date set to whole hours.

---

If you're writing a clock app with precision down to seconds for humans, it is easier to ignore sub-second differences and use `+scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...` directly, e.g.

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(updateClock)
                                                userInfo:nil 
                                                 repeats:YES];
...

-(void)updateClock {
  NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
  NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
  NSDateComponents* dateComps = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                            fromDate:now];

  NSInteger hourNow = [dateComps hour];
  NSInteger minuteNow = [dateComps minute];
  NSInteger secondNow = [dateComps second];
  // update clock view using 'hourNow', 'minuteNow' and 'secondNow'
  if (secondNow == 0) {
     // whole minute
     if (minuteNow == 0) {
        // whole hour
     }
     // (note: not very reliable since a timer does not need to fire on schedule)
}
```

Comment: I am using a method very similar to this already. What i need is a way to call a method every hour on the hour, or every minute on the minute to use as well.

Comment: @Storms: You could check if the seconds / minutes components are zero in `-updateClock`. It should be better than creating  3 timers.

Comment: @KennyTM: That sounds promising. I cant seem to find any info on that in the developer documentation. can you point me there?

Comment: @KennyTM: I guess I'm not really what you meant. I don't know how to check if the seconds or minutes are at zero. Sorry, basically im asking if you could possibly elaborate. I'm sure you have assumed by now but I'm pretty new at this.